# Referencing Style

Tags: bibliographies

My current references/bibliography at the end are in the style of:

> Kenneth J. Arrow, Leonid Hurwicz, and Hirofumi Uzawa. Constraint
>   qualifications in maximization problems. Naval Research Logistics
>   Quarterly, 8:175–191, 1961.

I'm trying to change it to:

> Arrow KJ, Hurwicz L, Uzara H (1961) Constraint qualifications in
>   maximization problems. Naval Research Logistics Quarterly, 8:175–191.

Any help (or advice for a more suitable referencing style). I like the citation style I have at the minute.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ahu61,
   author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
   title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
   journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
   volume={8},
   year = {1961},
   pages = {175-191}
 }
 \end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor \citep{ahu61} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Your example contains not the bibliography item `ahua61`.

Comment: Brian -- I've edited your addition of a `.bib` file so that it gets written automatically via a `filecontents` environment. It's a convenient trick when producing MWEs for bibliography related matters.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typical author-year style.

Have a look at Chicago, Harvard and apa styles. Very close: `apa` and `apalike`.

[image: brianBibStyle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{ahu61,
        author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
        title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
        journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
        volume={8},
        year = {1961},
        pages = {175-191}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor \citep{ahu61} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```